# How do I install photofilmstrip on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, python

When I try to install photofilmstrip, I am told that that there is a problem:

```
Error dependency is not satisfiable: pythonwxgtk2.8
```

When I tried to install it via Command line,

```
sudo apt-get install pythonwxgtk2.8
```

the result is:

```
Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I installed `pythonwxgtk3.0`, but photofilmstrip is still not installing. What should I do?

Answer (score 9):

It is because the development of the app stopped along time back. See https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/photofilmstrip/ It is available only upto Ubuntu 13.10 So if you are using a higher version you will not be able to install the app

However if you still want to install it, you can download the .deb installer pack from https://sourceforge.net/projects/photostoryx/ But remember that you will not get any apt-get update for it

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install the latest version of PhotoFilmStrip directly from Sourceforge [[here]](https://sourceforge.net/projects/photostoryx/files/photofilmstrip/2.9.95/)
Then install the base package

```
sudo dpkg -i photofilmstrip_3.0.0-1_all.deb
```

and the unmet dependencies

```
sudo apt -f install
```